# yum : Installing openvpn on centos not available

Tags: centos, openvpn, yum

I just installed a centos version on AWS. But I am not able to install openvpn.

When I try: `sudo yum -y install openvpn` I get this error message:

```
Geladene Plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * centosplus: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
Kein Paket openvpn verfügbar.
Fehler: Nichts zu tun
```

Sorry, this is in German (another thing that bothers me). But loosely translated it is like:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
     * centosplus: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
     * extras: mirror.imt-systems.com
     * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
No package openvpn available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

actually pretty weird. I do not understand why is does not find anything.

How do I solve this annoying problem?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105588/how-to-have-console-messages-in-english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenVPN is not available via standard repos available in cent os .. It's available via EPEL repository. First install EPEL repo and then install open vpn.

**Step 1: update cent os and Enable EPEL repository**

On CentOS 6:

```
sudo yum update -y
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

On CentOS 7:

```
sudo yum update -y
yum install epel-release
```

**Step 2: Install openvpn**

```
yum install -y openvpn easy-rsa
```

Source : 
https://www.quickservers.com/en/how-to-install-openvpn-on-centos.php
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7